# How to access polls in Tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm using the following code, but its giving me the error `KeyError: 'polls'`. In the API, it shows polls listed under entities. So, I'm a little confused why it's giving me this error.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/data-dictionary/native-enriched-objects/tweet

```
status.entities['polls']
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the Twitter API v2 in Tweepy?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I am

Comment: Could you please paste an entire example Tweet object you've received in your question?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The entire output of `print(status)`

Comment: How do I use the Twitter API v2 in Tweepy?